# Apache Tomcat выдает ошибку 404, не может найти сервлет

Tags: java, apache, servlet, tomcat

[image: не знаю как исправить эту ошибку]

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Формула:</h3>
 <p><img src="img/formula.png" alt="Мат формула"></p>
 <h3>Введите параметры:</h3>
<form action="/servlet">
 <input type="text" name="a">
 <input type="text" name="b">
 <input type="text" name="c">
 <input type="text" name="d">
 <input type="submit" name="кнопка" value="Вычислить">
</form>
</body>
</html>


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String aParam =  request.getParameter("a");
        String bParam =  request.getParameter("b");
        String cParam =  request.getParameter("c");
        String dParam =  request.getParameter("d");

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Решение‚</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        if (isNum(aParam) && isNum(bParam) && isNum(cParam) && isNum(dParam)) 
  {
            Double a = Double.parseDouble(aParam);
            Double b = Double.parseDouble(bParam);
            Double c = Double.parseDouble(cParam);
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(dParam);
            double result = Math.pow((2*Math.sin(a) + 
            Math.cos(Math.abs(b*Math.sqrt(c)))),d);
            out.println("<h3>Ответ:<h3>" + result);
        } else {
            response.sendError(400);
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
public static boolean isNum(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Web.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>WebApplication1.Servlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: web.xml показывайте

Comment: @StrangerintheQ или пусть аннотацию добавит

Comment: Добавил web.xml в вопрос

Comment: Ваш класс называется servlet (с маленькой буквы), а web.xml говорит нам другое: <servlet-class>WebApplication1.Servlet</servlet-class>. Ну и маппинг <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>, а на фото с ошибкой servlet (опять же с маленькой буквы)

Comment: я уже менял все буквы на маленькие и большие и все равно та же ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не найден сервлет(точнее, по пути по которому вы перешли ничего не лежит). Покажите ваш `xml.web`. Там должно быть что-то такое:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>путь_до_сервлета</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Или добавьте аннотацию к классу `servlet`: `@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = "/servlet")`

Вот так:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = "/servlet")

public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Comment: Я добавил , и все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @Егорлыга вы добавили аннотацию или в web.xml?

Comment: Я добавил аннотацию

Comment: @Егорлыга вы же передеплоили приложение?

Comment: Кстати, откуда вы запускаете: руками деплоите на томкат или из IDE? Если из IDE, то из какой? Может у вас что то неправильно настроено.

Comment: я запускаю с net beans

Comment: Какой проект вы сдавали? Веб приложение? У вас там должен быть файл index.jsp, попробуйте открыть его, он должен автоматически открыться по локалхост/порт/

Comment: Да , я создавал веб приложение , и открыл index.jsp

Comment: @Егорлыга так у вас открылся index.jsp? У вас аннотация так выглядит: `@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = "/servlet")` И имя класса с маленькой буквы?

Comment: Имя класса должно везде совпадать, если у вас класс начинается с `s`, то и в аннотации и в web.xml везде должно начинаться с `s`, а не с `S`.

Comment: @Егорлыга ну что, решили проблему?

Comment: да, спасибо большое )